# How to insert elements into a List using a recursive function and then print it in Ocaml

Tags: recursion, ocaml

What is the right way to append items to a list inside a recursive function?

```
let () =
    let rec main m l acc =
        if (acc = 3) then
            acc
        else
            if (m = 1) then
                l := 1 :: !l
                main (m - 1) l
            else if (m = 2) then
                l := 2 :: !l
                main (m - 1) l
            else
                l := m :: !l
                main (m - 1) l

    in l = ref []
    let main 10 l 0
    List.iter (fun l -> List.iter print_int l) l
```

another Example:

```
let () =
    let rec main m =
        if (m = 3) then m
        else
            l := m :: !l;
            main (m + 1) l

    in l = ref []
    let main 0 l
    List.iter (fun l -> List.iter print_int l) l
```

I want to append a value to a list inside a function and then print the elements of the list.

Comment: can you describe what you tried and explain the purpose of the code you sent?

Comment: @Butanium, I posted another example, I really just want to append elements to a list and then print the list.

Comment: There are any number of odds things going on in your second example. To start: `List.iter (fun l -> List.iter print_int l) l`: `List.iter` has type `('a -> unit) -> 'a list -> unit` so this infers `l` to be of type `int list list`, but `l` has been previously bound as a value of type `'a list ref`.  You also have `let main 0 l List.iter (fun l -> List.iter print_int l) l` which is not valid OCaml syntax.

Comment: You may find it very instructive to review [the List module API](https://ocaml.org/api/List.html). There is an append function. (And operator.)

Comment: @ChrisDutton I really don't understand nothing about that documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print [1;2;...;10]:

```
let () =
    let rec main m l =
        if (m = 0) then
            !l
        else begin
            l := m :: !l;
            main (m - 1) l
            end

    in 
    let l = ref [] in
    List.iter print_int (main 10 l); print_newline();;
```

or better without ref

```
let () =
    let rec main m l =
        if (m = 0) then
            l
        else 
            main (m - 1) (m::l)
    in 
    List.iter print_int (main 10 []); print_newline();;
```

but I am not sure of what you want to do...

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted it to do! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

What you mean by "the right way" is not quite clear. The functional "right way" would be not to use references. The efficiency "right way" would be to prepend rather than to append.

Another direct way to build a list inspired from user4624500's answer could be:

```
let rec f = function 
  | 0 -> [0]
  | n -> n :: f (n-1)
```

(note: that's not tail recursive, and would uglily fail with negative numbers...)

Then the following expression calls the previous function to build the list and then print the result (adding newlines for readability purposes):

```
let my_list = f 10 in
List.iter (fun n -> print_int n; print_newline ()) my_list
```